# Why array is copied

Tags: java, arrays

I need help because I can not see where my problem is. I have function swapping and it looks like this:

```
public static void swapping(int[] curr, Integer i, Integer j, Integer k, Integer l, int z, int dist) {
    int tmp;
    int[] tmpCurr = curr;
    if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && k < 0 && l < 0) {
        tmp = tmpCurr[i];
        tmpCurr[i] = tmpCurr[z];
        tmpCurr[z] = tmp;
        nodesHM.put(1, tmpCurr);
        for(int s = 0; s<tmpCurr.length; s++)
            System.out.println(tmpCurr[s]);

        tmpCurr = curr;
        tmp = tmpCurr[j];
        tmpCurr[j] = tmpCurr[z];
        tmpCurr[z] = tmp;
        nodesHM.put(2, tmpCurr);
        for(int s = 0; s<tmpCurr.length; s++)
            System.out.println(tmpCurr[s]);
    }
}
```

i,j,k,l tell me what to swap with z. So if i put that somethig is -1 that means I do not want to swap it. Like it this case k and l.

And I call it from main, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    swapping(ourStartState, 3, 7, -1, -1, 6, 5);
}

private static final int[] ourStartState = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8 };
```

And it should write me something like: 1,2,3,0,5,6,4,7,8 and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8

but it give me 1,2,3,0,5,6,4,7,8 and 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,4,8

Where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You are going wrong by not using a debugger and finding out exactly what is going wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you copy an array or an object, you just create another reference to the elements in the array.
so when you did tmpcurr=curr you created another reference to curr array, whatever changes you make in curr affects tmpcurr and vice-versa. 
if you swap elements in tmpcurr array the elements of curr get swapped as well.

when you swapped elements again you are swapping from already swapped array.

this will help you [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)